# I am running blockchain 0.9.4. Why is it not syncing?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, hard-fork

I know that you can send coins from 0.9.4 to 0.10.0. If I am still running 0.9.4 will it sync with 0.10.0 blocks?

I am trying to sync my 0.9.4 chain and it does not seem to be syncing any new blocks.

Comment: Could you post the output it is generating? That might give someone a clue at what is going wrong...

Answer (score 5):

"I know that you can send coins from 0.9.4 to 0.10.0" - I'm not sure what you mean by that? They aren't separate chains like Ethereum and Ethereum Classic, it's the same chain but a newer version of the software.

You can't use 0.9.4 as it's an old, deprecated version of the software. You need to update to 0.10.0, and you may want to sync up from scratch instead of waiting for the database to be converted to the newer format (database changes aren't common, so this won't occur with every upgrade).

Comment: Can't you actually still run 0.9.x until the next hardfork in January? I thought the 0.9.x software was aware of the hardfork last month. The caveat being that you have to use 0.9.x wallet software with 0.9.x daemon software...

Comment: @bigreddmachine it was aware of the fork date, but it wasn't aware of the changes, so no dice.

Comment: 0.9.4 should be able to sync fine till december. This is NOT the case with 0.9.3 and earlier, however. Also, note that at least one of the Windows .9.4 binaries from getmonero.org is a 0.9.3 binary due to a mistake, so that will not sync to the network now.

Comment: @user36303 except for the fees, it won't relay transactions below its minfee

Comment: Ah, good point. It should still sync fine though.